# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved

Tags: spring, tomcat7, aspectj, tomcat8

When I upgraded Apache Tomcat version from 7.0.57 to 8.0.33. I am facing this issue.

EDITED - ADDED my full stack trace

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bootstrap-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.specificToGenericStringHeader(Method.java:419)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Executable.sharedToGenericString(Executable.java:163)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.toGenericString(Method.java:414)
>       at java.beans.MethodRef.set(MethodRef.java:46)
>       at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:117)
>       at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
>       at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
>       at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1205)
>       at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
>       at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
>       at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224)
>       at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:324)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1242)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>       ... 56 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>       ... 90 more

Comment: I fixed it as I upgraded aspectj version to 1.8.9 and I am heading different issues now.

Comment: what are the issues?

Comment: I have edited. Please, see above.

Comment: did you try a project clean by going to Doing Project->Clean…

Comment: Yes, I use allways clean install -DskipTests

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace

Comment: just added my full stack trace.

Comment: Seems like a classpath problem, missing dependency.

Comment: I fixed it as I upgraded aspectj from 1.6.8 version to 1.8.9 and I am not heading this issues no more. However, I cannot post answer to my question.